# xquery beginner-- if some text follows a node, then is it a child node or a sibling

Tags: xquery

Take a look at the sample XML below--

```
 <div id="sample">
    <b>Some text</b>

    : Demetra R. Smith

    <b> Some more text </b>
</div>
```

Now, is the text "Demetra R. Smith" a "child node" of the 'b' node(that contains text 'Some text'? Or is it a 'next-sibling'?

How do you determine if some content is a sibling or a child-- esp. in this case the text "Demetra R. Smith" is not enclosed in any tag (else I would not be asking this question)?

Comment: As your "sample XML" is no well-formed XML document, the text is neither a child nor a following node. Please take some more time before posting questions.

Comment: @ChristianGrün - my apologies-- i have corrected the sample xml...

Comment: The text "Demetra R. Smith" is a child of the `<div>` element and is a sibling of the `<b>` elements. This is known as mixed content http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#mixedContent

Answer (score 1):

`Some text` is a child (text) node of the first `<b/>`-node. `: Demetra R. Smith` is a sibling, in this case a following-sibling of the `<b/>`-node (there is no next-sibling).

You could access it using

```
/div/b[1]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

which selects the first `<b/>`-node inside the (each) `<div/>`-element, looks for all text nodes on the following-sibling-axis and limits to the first of them. It will return

```
: Demetra R. Smith
```

Comment: Watch out that there are also text nodes between the opening <div...> tag and the opening <b> tag - the newline and paces.